# How to bind a grid in column in date time in particular format

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datetime, dataset

I'm trying to bind grid in C# using XML as data source

```
string sApplication = txtApplicationsta.Text.Trim();
if (sApplication=="")
{ 
     DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
     ds3.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("Status.xml"));
     if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
     {
          gvstatus.DataSource = ds3;
          gvstatus.DataBind();
     }
}
```

The data is bound successfully. I'm saving the date format as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Like below:

```
string idate = DateTime.Parse(ssplit[4].Trim()).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now I need to bind my grid column in `DD-MM-YYYY` Format but in grid its getting Bind by what I save.

I am binding the grid in Asp page like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Last Update' HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="chkbox" />
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" att='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")%>' Text='<%# SetLinkCodestatus(Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID")),DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LastUpdate").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="3%" HorizontalAlign="left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How can I bind the grid using `DD-MM-YYYY` format if I'm saving the value in `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Answer (score 3):

You've done too much work for simply displaying a date value in a `GridView` column. Instead of using an `TemplateField` with a `Label` control, use a simple `BoundField`.

Then, you can set the column's date format by using the `dataformatstring` property in your `BoundField` column:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="My_Date_Field" dataformatstring="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" />
                                                         ▲
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve formatting with the help of DataFormatString

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,##0.000}">
```

Comment: <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,##0.000}">

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LastUpdate")).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") )